# SQL Server Host Migration Datetime Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to move a SQL Server database from webfusion to heartinternet. It was easy enough to export the database and table structure but the insert statements don't work.

I get the following error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type
>   to a datetime data type resulted in an
>   out-of-range value.

Now this is one example of an insert statement:

```
INSERT [ECL_TRANSACTION] ([PUBLIC_USER_CODE], [TIMESTAMP], [TRANSACTION_TYPE], [TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION]) 
  VALUES (-9, '16/03/2011 06:30:19', 'A', 'Login Success')
```

The problem is that `datetime` field `[TIMESTAMP]` will not accept `16/03/2011 06:30:19`

I've read that you can use a cast or convert on each field to sort this but I've got 3000 insert statements and was wondering is there a way to apply some rule to all `datetime` fields to accept `DD/MM/YYY HH:MM:SS` format.

Any advice would be much appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

in your batches

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` at the start of your script.

**EDIT**

The following link also suggests a command enabling you to change the settings on the server instance, if you have that level of access...

[INF: How to Set the Day/Month/Year Date Format in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907)